# Application.Undo calling Worksheet_Change - I don't want this

Tags: vba, excel

When I use the function - `Application.Undo` - it triggers `Worksheet_Change` sub.

Is there a way to not call it or ignore when I use `Application.Undo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

before your call to `Application.Undo` and then:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

right afterwards to reset the original event handling state.